# Let $G$ be a non commutative group, show that $G$ has a non trivial subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me with this question, Since $G$ is not abelian, $G$ is not cyclic. Can i just take some element $a \in G$ and say that $\langle a \rangle$ forms a subgroup?

Comment: yes, it is simple :)

Comment: As long as $a$ is not the identity element.

Comment: but why make this a question, what is the key here that i need to take note of? So what if $G$ is abelian? or etc

Comment: If $G$ is abelian, it may be cyclic with every nontrivial element a generator: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p$ prime. Can you show that any other group has a nontrivial proper subgroup?